# Cut string from the second occurrence of a character to the end of the string

Tags: awk, sed

I would like to modify the end part of a file name in a script like the following

```bsh
    #!/bin/bash
    file = ...
    gawk -f shc2csv.awk $1 > $file.csv
```

where `$1` is typically something like `shc_20210901_0002_763803214.html` and `file` should be `shc_20210901`.

So the string should be cut from the second `_`.

How shall I obtain `file` from `$1` with sed or awk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need sed or awk to modify a value in a variable `$1`.

```
#!/bin/bash

file=${1%_*}    # remove the part after the last `_`
file=${file%_*} # repeat the removal to the second `_`

gawk -f shc2csv.awk "$1" > "$file".csv
```

You should quote variable expansions.

Comment: OK, thank you. I was expecting some fancy one-liner sed or awk, but I forgot indeed that bash also has string operators.

Comment: nice.. also with `bash` `extglob` (extended globs) - `echo ${file%_+([!_])_+([!_])}`

Comment: @iruvar Or we could call a regex: `[[ $1 =~ ^(.*)_([^_]+)_([^_]+)$ ]] && file="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"`